# How to add stroke to a video mask

Tags: masking, movie-clip-editor

Is it possible to add a stroke to a mask created in the Movie Clip Editor?

I've created a mask in a movie clip that I use for blurring parts of a movie clip. I wish to create a thin black line lining/stroking the mask. So in the attached example there would be a black circle around the mask/blurred part.

[image: Mask]

[image: Composite]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a border by creating a second circle, like a letter O. It will have to be in a different mask because the mask for blurring will have to stay as it is.

Then, in the Mask tab, check the Holes box for the border mask. This mask/border will have to be filled with color which you can do in the Video Sequencer.

In the Video Sequencer, go to Add->Color and it will add a color strip. After clicking the color strip, go to the Modifiers tab.

At the Add Strip Modifier drop-down, choose Mask. It will generate a new panel/section that says Mask. Click the down arrow then choose the border mask you created.

To be able to show the other strips below, go to the Strip tab, then to Compositing, then at the Blend mode choose Alpha Over. This will make the transparent areas 'truly transparent'.

Then you'll have to add your movie (with the blur) in the Video Sequencer by clicking Add->Movie. The movie should be below the color strip or border.

To rearrange the movie and border, go to the Strip tab then to Channel - it has arrows for moving strips higher or lower.

By the way, you can also add Blur in the Video Sequencer. So you can do the blur and stroke in one place.